# Will you create a private class member to eliminate multi-level function call?

Tags: c++, oop, refactoring

Although I wrote this example in C++, this code refactoring question also applies to any language that endorses OO, such as Java.

Basically I have a class A

```
class A
{
public:
  void f1();
  void f2();
  //..
private:
  m_a;
};

void A::f1()
{
  assert(m_a);
  m_a->h1()->h2()->GetData();
  //..
}

void A::f2()
{
  assert(m_a);
  m_a->h1()->h2()->GetData();
  //..
}
```

Will you guys create a new private data member `m_f` holding the pointer `m_a->h1()->h2()`? The benenif I can see is that it effectively eliminates the multi-level function calls which does simplify the code a lot.

But from another point of view, it creates an "unnecessary" data member which can be deduced from another existing data member `m_a`, which is kinda redundant?

I just come to a dilemma here. By far, I cannot convince myself to use one over the other.

Which do you guys prefer, any reason?

Comment: What is there `Java` tag ?

Comment: @Bhavik, Like I said, it's a question also applying to Java development:)

Comment: There is an `OOP` tag and a `Language-Agnostic` tag.

Comment: @Joe, Thanks. Should I remove Java and C++ tag and use those tags instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fancy word for this technique is *caching*: you calculate a two-away reference once, and *cache* it in the object. In general, caching lets you "pay" with computer memory for speed-up of your computations.

If a profiler tells you that your code is spending a significant amount of time in the repeated call of `m_a->h1()->h2()`, this may be a legitimate optimization, provided that the return values of `h1` and `h2` never change. However, doing an optimization like that without profiling first is nearly always a bad sign of a premature optimization.

If performance is not the issue, a good rule is to stay away from storing members that can be calculated from other members stored in your object. If you would like to improve clarity, you can introduce a nicely named method (a member function) to calculate the two-away reference without storing it. Storing makes sense only in the rare cases when it is critical for the performance.

Comment: I believe the OP is looking to optimize readability, not performance

Comment: Yes, the performance is not that critical in my case. So you usually just use the direct function calls?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you, now it addresses the issue better. I would like to add though. I have had this situation as well, where the multiple reference was actually a list lookup (small list) but the ultimate pointer was static for the life of the program. In this case I dont think there is a significant downside to doing caching even for the moderate gain, if it is static for the life of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I would not. I agree it would simply things in your contrived example, but that's because `m_a->h1()->h2()` has no inherent meaning. In a well-designed application, the method names used should tell you something qualitative about the calls being made, and that should be a part of self-documenting code. I would argue that in properly designed code, `m_a->h1()->h2()` should be *simpler to read and understand* than redirecting to a private method which calls it for you.

Now, if `m_a->h1()->h2()` is an expensive call which takes a significant time to compute the result, then you might have an argument for caching as @dasblinkenlight suggests. But throwing away the descriptiveness of the method call for the sake of a few keypresses is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have something like this I usually store m_a->h1() into a variable with a meaningful name at function scope since it's likely to be used again later in function's body.